# How to initialize shared_ptr not knowing its type?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, make-shared

I have a template function, that should get `std::shared_ptr<sometype>`.
Inside of function I want to make a temporary variable with `std::shared_ptr<sometype>`, but I can't put sometype as template param because I don't know it.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<typename sometypePtr>
void foo()
{
    sometypePtr tmp_ptr = std::make_shared<sometype>();  //compilation error, because we don't know sometype
}

int main()
{
    foo<std::shared_ptr<int>>();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some common way of making variable with `std::shared_ptr<sometype>` type?

Comment: Why is your template argument `typename sometypePtr` instead of just `typename sometype`?

Comment: A [mre] of what you're trying to do (even if it doesn't compile) might help explain your problem better

Comment: BTW, in the body of your template, you could replace `sometypePtr ptr` with either `std::shared_ptr<typename> ptr` or `auto ptr`.

Comment: Unless you're actually sharing ownership `std::shared_ptr` is probably the wrong choice, you should probably use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: `std::make_shared<typename sometypePtr::element_type>()` might be what you need?

Comment: The keyword auto was introduced exactly for situations like this, when you just cannot know the type until you instantiate a template and the compiler must figure it out by itself.

Comment: Oops, yep.  comment deleted.

Comment: @NathanOliver, you should probably leave even wrong ideas, so that people who read it later will understand, why it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `sometypePtr` is a non-array `std::shared_ptr`, then you can use `sometypePtr::element_type`.

```
template<typename sometypePtr>
void foo()
{
    sometypePtr ptr = std::make_shared<typename sometypePtr::element_type>();
}
```

If `sometypePtr` is an array `std::shared_ptr`, you will have to supply the extent as well as the type.

Comment: what is the problem with arrays here?

Comment: @mouse_00 `std::shared_ptr<int[100]>::element_type` is `int`

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same<typename sometypePtr::element_type, int[100]>::value);` succeeded while `static_assert(std::is_same<typename sometypePtr::element_type, int>::value);` failed

Comment: @mouse_00 [no?](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8994c81756158e43)

Comment: @mouse_00 note that `shared_ptr` didn't support arrays until c++17 so the definition of `element_type` was changed in c++17 to support that